# Issue with date for px bar but not px scatter

Tags: python, datetime, plotly

I am having issues to create a bar plot using px. I tested with px scatter and everything is displayed correctly as a scatter.

For the bar: the year is correctly displayed on the hover but not on the axis, each increment is 40 years instead of a month. The month is correctly displayed everywhere.

Background: I have a list of file with YYYYMM in the name (202201 is January 2022). I have a code on Jupyter to get the list of file, get the date part in string format, then convert to dt using:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['dateSTR'], format = '%Y%m')
```

On the bar plot, you can see that the month is correct, the year is not. If I used df['date'].dt.year, I get the correct year, the hover shows the correct year, but the axis has the incorrect year.

If I change the min max of the axis using xrange['2018-01-01','2024-01-01'], it zooms to the first data element, and I can see that each increement is 40 years instead of 1 month.

```
fig_1 = px.bar(df
       , x='countryCode', y='date', color='status', orientation='v'           
       , color_continuous_scale = ['white','#1b95e0']
      )
fig_1.update(layout_coloraxis_showscale=False)
fig_1.update_yaxes(tickformat="%b %Y")
fig_1.show()
```

[Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BT0Fu.png)
here are the data (Image 2) The date column is datetime and the dateSTR column is string (same behavior in both cases)

[BarPlot_issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G4eDW.png)

Any idea?

Comment: How about setting `dtick` in `update_yaxes`? For example: `fig_1.update_yaxes(dtick="M1", tickformat="%b %Y")`

Comment: No, I have tried this. The month displays correctly but the year is something like 5000, 6000... I have no issues with px scatter, only px.bar.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is not really a plotly problem, but more so that this type of visualization (stacked bar chart with date y-axis) doesn't work fundamentally.

I'll explain what I mean using a code example based on the code you provided:

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

df = pd.DataFrame({"countryCode": ["CO1", "CO1", "CO3"], "date": ["2022-01-01", "2022-01-01", "2022-03-03"]})
fig = px.bar(df, x='countryCode', y='date')
fig.show()
```

The above code gives this figure:

[image: example]

In the dummy date I've used here we have two data points with the same `x` and `y`. Plotly sees the two data points have the same `x` value so it tries to stack the bars. The first bar gets the correct date (y value), but since the second bar is put on top the date on the y-axis value doesn't make sense for the second bar.

A stacked bar chart with a numerical y-axis works, because the height of the bars stacked together correspond with the y-axis.

Example from plotly documentation:

[image: example2]

Using a scatter chart works here because the points don't stack and if there are two points with the same `x` and `y` it will just show one point.